# Where are activex data objects 2.7 stored procedures found?

Tags: stored-procedures, vb6

I'm attempting to fix some problems with some old VB6 code for a client, and the previous programmer used Activex Data Object 2.7 stored procedures.  After a recent computer failure and reimage, none of the buttons that use stored procedures in the application currently work.

So, my question is where can these procedures be stored?
Thanks

Comment: stored procedures are in the database (which one are you using) ?

Comment: Can you be more clear than that the buttons don't work?  Is there an error message of some kind?

Comment: When you say you're trying to fix some old code, does that mean you can examine the code and see what enables the buttons? The programmer could have done a lot of things. The procedures might have been text stored in files in the app folder, or a sub-folder.

Comment: Rafael MS SQL Server. The DSN Provider is SQLOLEDB.1 if that helps.
tcarvin no error message, everything happens in the code aside from the stored procedure doing what it's supposed to do
Beaner Yes, I can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure are on the database. Unless the database was on the local machine, there are only a few things of which I can think that could have been broken/reset by a re-image.

These are all used to remap computer name references.

1. HOSTS
2. DSN
3. SQL Aliases